# Hadoop shell command VS Java APIs

Tags: java, api, hadoop

I faced a performance issue while writing an utility to delete files and directories from hdfs iteratively within a loop (was invoking the shell command from shell script) that were older than a week. Also I had certain checks to be performed on each file/sub-directory before deleting, so that I could not just delete the entire root directory. For each delete, the shell command was taking around 2 sec. So If I had to delete 1600 files and subdirectories, it was taking close to 1 hr to accomplish them. When I instead used the JAVA APIs (FileStatus and FileSystem), I got a drastic performance gain. It completed under 5 secs. I would like to know in detail the fundamental reason behind this. I read that shell commands (like -rm) intrenally use the JAVA APIs but is that the sole reason for this huge difference in response time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well invoking the shell command iterative, you have the JVM startup time to contend with for each iteration, while the API approach you only have one JVM startup. Along these lines you have to connect to the name node multiple times etc.